# Has/have the materials arrived?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

I understand that you use "has" when it's singular, and "have" when it's plural. However I've always heard "has the materials I ordered arrived?"
In this case, is it "has the materials arrived?" or "have the materials arrived?"

Comment: "The materials" is plural, so you'll need to use "have", not "has".

Comment: Where, or who,  have you heard it from all the time? Unless *the materials* is conceived as a unit (and that would be unusual to rare),  *have* is used. Maybe the person is speaking nonstandard English.

Comment: One might say "Has the material arrived?" or "Have the materials arrived?"  Saying "Has the materials arrived?" is, at best, non-standard.

Comment: No, even if the materials is a unit, it would be plural.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of `has` and `have` is correct. The sentence that you have quoted, however, is not.

It should either be

> Have the materials arrived?

or

> Has the material arrived?